# PoU with non-shareable attribute

Tags: caching, arm

Another question regarding caching in ArmV7-A. 
In this case, the SoC in question is Allwinner A20, Dual-Core Cortex-A7.

From what I have read, The definition of PoU for a core is the point at which the instruction and data caches of the core are guaranteed to see the same copy of a memory location.

In regards to SoC in question, since both cores share PoU at L2 (Unified) Cache, it means that whatever is put in L1, will be visible to L2. Is that right?

Even if I change an attribute of a memory region to be Non-Shareable, L2 will be able to see what inside L1 *in either core*. Is that true?

To elaborate what I meant by that, I have done a little experiment:

When I wrote into an memory address inside a **Non-Shareable, Write-Back** region from core #0. Then without doing any Cache Maintenance operation, when I tried to read from the same memory address from core #1, it happened that it read the correct value which was written from core #0.

I speculated that the behaviour was a result from L2 being the PoU, so, when I wrote from core#0, L2 also store a copy of it (even if it's not flushed). Then when I read from core#1, after a read miss, core#1's L1 retreive the memory value from L2.

Comment: Writing from one CPU and _reading_ from another has nothing to do with the PoU, because both are _data_ accesses.

Comment: @Notlikethat Thanks also for the other question. Could you elaborate? Does PoU has nothing to do with data access? I still don't know why the other cpu can access the content I wrote at the first cpu. Provided that the region settin is Non-Shareable, Writeback

Answer (score 1):

> ...since both cores share PoU at L2 (Unified) Cache, it means that whatever is put in L1, will be visible to L2. Is that right?

No. One CPU's data accesses may snoop the data caches of another in the same shareability domain, but that has nothing to do with the PoU for instruction accesses; it's just the coherency protocol.

> Even if I change an attribute of a memory region to be Non-Shareable, L2 will be able to see what inside L1 in either core. Is that true?

No. Non-shareable memory is not guaranteed to be coherent. Sure, you *might* see it work - maybe Cortex-A7 happens to still snoop non-shareable cache lines, or maybe your data just got naturally evicted from L1D in the meantime such that the other CPU hit it at L2 - but it definitely should not be relied upon. Either way, having multiple CPUs access the same non-shareable location is a totally backwards thing to do in practice; you've deliberately said you don't want to share it!

Comment: Thanks! I haven't check if ReadNoSnoop for Non-Shareable memory region is actually implementation defined or required for Cortex-A7. What I am doing is actually checking my assumption on Non-Shareable region, and my assumption was that it should be exclusive to a cpu only. Your answer did answers some of my doubt, however, I will leave this question unanswered for the time being.

Comment: I'd imagine the L2 to send a ReadNoSnoop transaction out onto the ACE interface if a non-shareable load misses there, so I wouldn't expect such 'accidental' coherency between clusters in a multi-cluster system - within a single cluster, though, things are rather more tightly-coupled, and you're essentially looking at implementation details of the SCU.

Comment: here is what I saw from the internal memory access, using the encoding listed at Cortex-A53 TRM: After I wrote from cpu0, the cache line in L1D cpu0 is `Modified`, then, only after I read from cpu1, the L1D cpu1 cache line became `Owned`, and L1D cpu0 became `Shared`.